# jQuery .when() is getting ignored in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, loops, .when

I have a custom loop that needs to execute a function before going into the next iteration. This is the code:

```
function customIteration(arr, i)
{
    if (i==arr.length) return;
    var message = arr[i];
    jQuery('#stepTwo #num1StepTwo').html('Expires: ' + $num1);
    jQuery('#stepTwo #num2StepTwo').html(jQuery(message).find('.num2').text());
    jQuery('#stepTwo #num3StepTwo').html(jQuery(message).find('.num3').text());
    i++;
    jQuery.when(mySpecialFunction()).then(customIteration(arr, i));
}
```

mySpecialFunction():

```
function mySpecialFunction(){
    return jQuery.ajax({
        url: "https://api.site.com/customurl",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: { data1: $data1, data2: $data2 },
        success: function (data) {
            ...some code...
        },
        error: function (e) {
            ...some other code...
        }
    });
}
```

problem is, I see in Fiddler that the url is being hit immediately by all the instances of the loop above, without waiting to get a response from the ajax code inside mySpecialFunction(). This is of course messes up the results I should get.

Comment: Change `.then(customIteration(arr, i))` to `.then(function(){ customIteration(arr, i) })`.

Comment: @A1rPun this actually worked! Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .done()

in fact,

.done() has only success callback.

.then() has both success and fail callbacks.

As of jQuery 1.8, the deferred.then() method returns a new promise that can filter the status and values of a deferred through a function, replacing the now-deprecated deferred.pipe() method.

The deferred.done() method accepts one or more arguments, all of which can be either a single function or an array of functions.

Since deferred.done() returns the deferred object, other methods of the deferred object can be chained to this one, including additional  .done() methods. When the Deferred is resolved, doneCallbacks are executed using the arguments provided to the resolve or resolveWith method call in the order they were added.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using .done() and a recursive function, should be easier to implement and understand.
Like this:

```
 (function recursive(arr,i){
   jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://api.site.com/customurl",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: { data1: $data1, data2: $data2 },
    success: function (data) {
        ...some code...
    },
    error: function (e) {
        ...some other code...
    }
}).done(function(data){
       var message = arr[i];
       jQuery('#stepTwo #num1StepTwo').html('Expires: ' + $num1);
       jQuery('#stepTwo#num2StepTwo').html(jQuery(message).find('.num2').text());
       jQuery('#stepTwo #num3StepTwo').html(jQuery(message).find('.num3').text());
       if(i!=arr.length){
       recursive(++i); 
       }
 }); /// End done
})(0); ///End recursive function
```

What this does is make sure your single iteration ends before calling itself up again and continuing iterating. 
So basically your function is calling itself when it's done with a single iteration, and continues until everything has been iterated, then stops.